# issue in watermark textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to wpf.I downloaded the wpf toolkit and then added it's dll file into my project file.Then tried some code to create watermark textbox but showing error(The tag 'WatermarkTextBox' does not exist in XML namespace).

```
<Window 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"  
x:Class="TRAINING.WaterMark"
x:Name="Window"
Title="WaterMark"
Width="640" Height="480">
<extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox>
        <extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox.Watermark>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Contact16.png" Stretch="None" />
                <TextBlock Text="Enter First Name" Margin="4,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox.Watermark>
    </extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox>  
</Window>
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Where are you referencing `extToolkit` as a namespace?

Comment: I'm sure you already done that but did you check the reference on the toolkit? Is it added in your project (right-click, "Add Reference", or better use Nuget)?

Answer (score 3):

I have not used the wpf toolkit before, but I'm pretty sure that as you have added the namespace using `xctk`, then you should use that in the xaml - i.e. `xctk:WatermarkTextBox` instead of `extToolkit:WatermarkTextbox`

Answer (score 1):

```
<Window 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:extToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit/extended"
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"  
x:Class="TRAINING.WaterMark"
x:Name="Window"
Title="WaterMark"
Width="640" Height="480">
<extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox>
        <extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox.Watermark>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Contact16.png" Stretch="None" />
                <TextBlock Text="Enter First Name" Margin="4,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox.Watermark>
    </extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox>  
</Window>
```

I Guess You Missed the refrence of that extToolkit so i added. i hope it will help you

Comment: It is not work. it is also showing error(The tag 'WatermarkTextBox' does not exist in XML namespace)

Answer (score 0):

My reason for this issue was confusion between xceed ($) vs dotnetprojects (Free) NuGet package.

So once I uninstalled the xceed, everything was working fine and error was resolved.